# Converting nvarchar to int datatype from a select query stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I had this problem on converting nvarchar datatype from a select query using stored procedure into Integer datatype and insert it into my database;

I already search the internet many times on how to solve my problem but, the codes i found was not able to solve my problem.

This is my code,

```
USE [SLCBRegistrarDB]
 GO
 /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CountLabfees]    Script Date: 
 10/30/2017 7:06:43 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER Procedure [dbo].[CountLabfees]
 @LabSubject nvarchar(50)

 as

 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 Declare @SQL NVARCHAr(MAX)
 SET @LabSubject = REPLACE(@LabSubject,',',''',''')
 SET @SQL='SELECT Distinct(TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Code])
 FROM TESTFeeSETUP INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee 
 Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification ID]
 WHERE TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification in (''' + @LabSubject + ''')'

 Declare @Quantity NVARCHAr(MAX)
 SET @Quantity='SELECT Count(FEESList.[Fee Description]) AS Quantity
 FROM FEESList INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUP ON FEESList.FeeID = 
 TESTFeeSETUP.FeeID INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee 
 Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification ID]
 WHERE TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification in (''' + @LabSubject + ''')'

 Declare @Total NVARCHAr(MAX)
 SET @Total='SELECT Distinct(TESTFeeSETUP.[Amount/Cost])
 FROM TESTFeeSETUP INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee 
 Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification ID]
 WHERE TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification in (''' + @LabSubject + ''')'

 EXEC (@SQL)
 EXEC (@Total)
 EXEC (@Quantity)
 END
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO FeesStudentBILLING VALUES(10,@SQL,@Quantity,@Total,1,1)
 END
```

Everytime I execute the code, this error always appears,

> "Cannot convert nvarchar datatype 'SELECT Count(FEESList.[Fee
>   Description]) AS Quantity FROM FEESList INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUP ON
>   FEESList.FeeID = TESTFeeSETUP.FeeID INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON
>   TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification
>   ID] WHERE TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification in (''' + @LabSubject +
>   ''')' into integer datatype"

I am new to programming, so I really need some help on this please. thanks

Comment: It seems like your `[Fee Specification]` is not int. try `CAST([Fee Specification] as int)`

Comment: Why did you use the dynamic query? It would be much more simple if you just implement the normal query. Show me the FeesStudentBILLING table schema, I will show you how to do that.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but its just the same result.

Comment: @Edward I was trying to find a way where i have to select a specific primary key with IN clause.. Its hard for me to demonstrate, if you could just take a closer look at the code i made., i'm struggling in it, i really badly need some help.

Comment: @Edward I was trying to find a way where i have to select a specific primary key with IN clause.. Its hard for me to demonstrate, if you could just take a closer look at the code i made., i'm struggling in it, i really badly need some help.

Answer (score 0):

It's so much easier for you, if you do something like:

1. Using the split string function to get values from your @LabSubject, and then stored them in local variable table.
2. Using the local variable table in step 1 with your condition query.

**For example** (SQL Server 2016)

```
    DECLARE @LabSubjectTable TABLE(Value NVARCHAR(50))

        INSERT INTO @LabSubjectTable 
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@LabSubject, ',')


         SELECT Distinct(TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Code]) AS FeeCode
FROM TESTFeeSETUP AS t1
INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification ID]
WHERE TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification in (SELECT value FROM @LabSubjectTable)


 SELECT Count(FEESList.[Fee Description]) AS Quantity
 FROM FEESList INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUP ON FEESList.FeeID = TESTFeeSETUP.FeeID 
 INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification ID]
 WHERE TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification in (SELECT value FROM @LabSubjectTable)


 SELECT Distinct(TESTFeeSETUP.[Amount/Cost]) AS AmountCost
 FROM TESTFeeSETUP INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification ID]
 WHERE TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification in (SELECT value FROM @LabSubjectTable)
```

Updated:

- I think you can get the ideas now. Based on that, you can update according to your logic.
- If your SQL Server does not support built in split string function, you can create one [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Comment: But my problem is, How about the @LabSubject? How can i set multiple values in my IN cluase and how will I going to execute my code with that query?

Comment: Whats with the INSERT query? what does it do with the select query? I think my problem is how to set multiple values into single variable.. i was able to do it with the code i provided but it does not convert it to Integer. Can you explain it more for me how to do it.?

Comment: @Edward..I had this error while editing the code "Incorrect syntax near 'TESTFeeSETUP'. Expecting '(', or SELECT". Please help.

Comment: Hi, it's really hard to give you a full query without knowing about logic. I think your first problem is solved. If you are facing problem to develop a query, I think you can ask another question, and provide sample data for each table, as well as an expected result, it will easier to everyone to help you out.

Comment: But can you help me if i'll be giving you the whole scenario? Including my database structure?

Comment: @deitysha you should post it, so anyone can help out

Comment: I already posted my question but i've changed the title..please check on it